# GAS development version in iFrame does not work

Tags: google-apps-script, iframe, deployment, web-applications

I have a simple GAS web application that I used in iFrame. It works nicely -  see [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/radek/83vq0ewc/2/)

The same, exactly the same code but DEV mode in Iframe does not work because of `Refused to display 'https://script.google.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'`.

see [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/radek/q68bw4na/)

I am using

`htmlTemplate.evaluate().setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);`

and the same iFrame set up for both scenarios

```
<iframe src="https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzPRpQ6nNLJx2w0aai_GRfYaPUvNnR8sKsGNfQW4BCL/dev" style="overflow:hidden;overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:hidden;height:85%;width:100%;position:absolute;top:505x;left:0px;right:0px;bottom:0px;"></iframe>
```

The project is deployed

- executed as me
- who can access - anyone

I tried to access the dev iframe also in a browser while being logged into my Google account.

Could someone suggest how to make DEV work in iFrame?

Comment: Have you tried [.setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.DEFAULT](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/x-frame-options-mode)?

Comment: @doubleunary, yes I did. It did not help.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to happen when you are required to log in. For example: if you deploy the web app with only can access it, it will also get blocked.

As a workaround what you can do the following:

1. Create a new project
2. Add the original web app as a library (on HEAD)
3. Forward the `doGet` function (see below)
4. Deploy with executed as you, everyone can access

```js
function doGet() {
  return WebApp.doGet.apply(this, arguments)
}
```

Now you this deployment will automatically update its contents. So basically the dev is another project and another non-related URL.

#### Update

For using `google.script.run` you'll need to use an intermediate function that calls the WebApp one:

```js
function forward(name, ...args) {
  if (!(name in WebApp)) {
    throw new Error(`Function "${name}" does not exist.`)
  }
  return WebApp[name].apply(this, args)
}
```

Then you can use a Proxy ([read MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)) to generate the function on the fly:

```js
const run = new Proxy({}, {
  get(target, prop, receiver) {
    const r = google.script.run
    if (prop in r) {
      if (r[prop].name) {
        // default functions
        return undefined
      }
      return (...args) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(resolve)
          .withFailureHandler(reject)
          [prop](...args)
      })
    } else {
      return (...args) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(resolve)
          .withFailureHandler(reject)
          .forward(prop, ...args)
      })
    }
  }
});
```

This works on both projects and will return a Promise ([read MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)). To use it you can just:

```js
run.functionName(arg1, arg2).then(onSuccess, onFailure)
```

Or if you are on an async context ([read MDN guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await)) you can simply use:

```js
const result = await run.functionName(arg1, arg2)
```

Comment: such workaround woud require to have two projects.. one for dev project and one for other versions. It seems to me that it did not work like that before

Comment: Do you have a reason that prevents you to do this?

Comment: my project is not just one doGet(). To transfer it so library is used and then manage two projects seems to me now as too much overhead. If it is the only way how to have running DEV in iFrame then I might have to do it.

Comment: I've realized that I was not passing the arguments so I've improved the answer. On the other hand, the idea of this answer is to only use this project for the web app: that is, as way of having another URL for the development version. You do not need to do the same for each function just `doGet` and possibly `doPost` if needed, and this project can be deployed once and left alone as it should never need any updates, so in practical terms it becomes just a URL.

Comment: how about javascript fungcions called from HTML? I got few of them, they need to be in the library project too.

Comment: I didn't think about that. It's possible to have a function that automatically generates bindings to forward all the functions using the Apps Script API. I've tried and works perfectly. Let me know if this would help you as I would clean it up and add it to the answer.

Comment: That wouldn't work as you would have to deploy them every time. Added a better way with a forwarding function and a Proxy on the frontend to have a nice syntax :)